# webview not always working when trying to open pdf

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to open pdf with webview in android studio. I have managed to do that, the problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

i have tried all suggestions I found on stack and youtube and other but none of them seem to work.

```java
public class EverythingWeDoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_everything_we_do);setTitle("Unser sämtliches Tun");

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        String katalog = "http://website/katalogapp.pdf";
        String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + katalog;

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EverythingWeDoActivity.this,"", "Loading...",true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progressDialog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                Toast.makeText(EverythingWeDoActivity.this, "Error occurred: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

This is the class where I have put only webview, and in my MainActivity when I press on menu_action_bar button I would like it to open this activity (i've done that, no problems here) and to ALWAYS open the url (if there is connection). Right now it works lets say arouond 50% of times, even if I have internet connection and I've allowed internet permission in manifest,...

PS: I never get the toast error message !

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html

Comment: Thats one of the options, but what if my user does not have an app to open pdf which is highly likely in my case....I am not against it, but in this case I have to use other ways

Comment: If you read the blog post, I discuss several options, not just one. Only one of those options -- albeit the recommended one -- involves using a PDF app.

Comment: PdfREnderer is way to much work plus I have no idea where to start and it seems like to much hassle for just showing pdf, I might as well just use ACTION_VIEW. PDF.js and pdfium are fine but just for newer android versions plus also I have no idea where to start here. All in all this just seems like to much work for a relative simple thing. I would prefer to stick with simple stuff which is either action_view or redirect to google docs....

Comment: And what proof do you have that Google will keep that URL working indefinitely? The pdfium option works back to at least Android 4.1, as I noted in the blog post. [Here are three sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/PDF) showing the techniques that I mention in the blog post.

Comment: None. All I can do is hope :p In that case I would just change it to ACTION_VIEW and thats it. Thank you for samples I will try to work something out :)